# cv2.waitKey returns 255 for all keys

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to read the key value using cv2.waitKey(0) but it doesn't work. It waits forever. I used cv2.waitKey(1) to check what it returns and it was always 255 no matter which key I pressed.

```
while True:
      key = cv2.waitKey(0)
      print(key)
```

The above code does nothing, no matter whichever key I press.

```
while True:
     key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
     print(key)
     if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

keeps printing 255 and doesn't break if I press 'q'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out the solution.
Looks like ***it requires a named window to be open for it to read the key values***. So I tried the following and it worked.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    key=cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
    print(key)
    if key == ord('q'):
         break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I was actually drafting an answer, and then you realized. Good Job.